# CreateIfNotExists() of CloudBlobContainer always throw status code 400

Tags: .net, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, blobstorage

I try to run demo follow documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started

and from github template project: https://github.com/CawaMS/ContosoAdsCloudServices?fbclid=IwAR0gn_t-OsKpLrLyOdUd1qVa1-e0A2jIPZoHspev-4dj5mXCI-ZPxGaZpic

I have some problem when process with AzureStorage, for example:
[Image detail code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV2nv.png)

This code always throw exception code 400. Web Role is running good but i stuck at WorkerRole with this exception. Code connect is the same. I have checked that all connection string are right. Thanks a lot for supporting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several reasons for this error. Below are some listed ones, I would suggest you to try/verify all the findings:

- Do you have a container with same name but different casing than "images"?
- Is the default port of blob emulator (10000) being used by another app/software?
- Are the versions of your emulator and solution libraries in sync?

Try to avoid using Upper Case in naming of container if possible.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to check version of my emulator with current libraries(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v8.0.1.0) ?
I have check port is exactly 10000 for blob and container name advoid uppser case.

Comment: You can check it in your "Add or Remove Programs" section in Control Panel. The available versions are: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#storage-emulator-release-notes Basically, both versions should be updated and latest.

Comment: Yah, my emulator verson is latest. I realized that when running in single web role is running ok, but when I start Azure Cloud Service project is always throw 400 in spite of the same code.